# How to add a column count to table and still keep the original rows?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have one table named GUYS(ID, NAME, PHONE), and I need to add a count of how many guys have the same name, and at the same time show all of them. So I can't group them.

Example:

```
ID NAME  PHONE
1  John  335   
2  Harry 444
3  James 367
4  John  742
5  John  654
```

The desired output should be:

```
ID NAME  PHONE COUNT
1  John  335   3
2  Harry 444   1
3  James 367   1
4  John  742   3
5  John  654   3
```

How could I do that? I only managed to get a lot of guys with different counts.

Thanks

Answer (score 42):

**Update for 8.0+**: This answer was written well before MySQL version 8, which introduced [window functions](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/) with mostly the same syntax as the existing ones in Oracle.

In this new syntax, the solution would be

```
SELECT
  t.name,
  t.phone,
  COUNT('x') OVER (PARTITION BY t.name) AS namecounter
FROM
  Guys t
```

The answer below still works on newer versions as well, and in this particular case is just as simple, but depending on the circumstances, these window functions are way easier to use.

---

**Older versions**: Since MySQL, until version 8, didn't have [analytical functions like Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), you'd have to resort to a sub-query.

Don't use `GROUP BY`, use a sub-select to count the number of guys with the same name:

```
SELECT
  t.name,
  t.phone,
  (SELECT COUNT('x') FROM Guys ct 
   WHERE ct.name = t.name) as namecounter
FROM
  Guys t
```

You'd think that running a sub-select for every row would be slow, but if you've got proper indexes, MySQL will optimize this query and you'll see that it runs just fine.

In this example, you should have an index on `Guys.name`. If you have multiple columns in the `where` clause of the subquery, the query would probably benefit from a single combined index on all of those columns.

Comment: I expected this query to perform slower than redfilter's answer, but that was not the case in my testing.  With a million row database, it completed in less than half the time.  I do have 'name' indexed.

Comment: Worked well in sqlite, using ```using System.Data.SQLite;```

Answer (score 36):

Use an aggregate Query:

```
select g.ID, g.Name, g.Phone, count(*) over ( partition by g.name ) as Count
from 
Guys g;
```

Comment: `COUNT ... OVER (...)` is not MySQL syntax, and this question is tagged MySQL.

Comment: Though this is not for MySQL, this is much better solution for Oracle folks. Thanks Sowmia!

Comment: This the best answer. We can apply over any kind of grouped results also. No performance issue.

Answer (score 20):

You can still use a `GROUP BY` for the count, you just need to `JOIN` it back to your original table to get all the records, like this:

```
select g.ID, g.Name, g.Phone, gc.Count
from Guys g
inner join (
    select Name, count(*) as Count
    from Guys
    group by Name
) gc on g.Name = gc.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle DB you can use

`SELECT ID,NAME,PHONE,(Select COUNT(ID)From GUYS GROUP BY Name)
FROM GUYS ;`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tbl table 
(ID int,NAME varchar(20), PHONE int)
insert into @tbl
select 
1  ,'John',  335   
union all
select 
2  ,'Harry', 444
union all
select 
3  ,'James', 367
union all
select 
4  ,'John',  742
union all
select 
5  ,'John',  654

SELECT
 ID
 , Name
 , Phone
 , count(*) over(partition by Name)
FROM @tbl 
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, name, phone,(select count(name) from users u1 where u1.name=u2.name) count from users u2
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
select column1, count(1) over ()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).