# CROSS JOIN in complicated query

Tags: mysql

How can I cross join the result of this query with itself?

sql-fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88f5e2/2

```
SELECT t.tid ,count(*) AS count
FROM taxonomy_index t 
JOIN taxonomy_term_data td ON td.tid = t.tid
WHERE t.created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3 * 86400 AND td.vid = 1
GROUP BY t.tid
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

the query result is:

```
tid count
4429    6
2634    5
1703    4
1742    4
4468    4
```

I need:

```
4429    4429       6
2634    4429       5
1703    4429       4
1742    4429       4
4468    4429       4
4429    2634       .
2634    2634       .
1703    2634       .
1742    2634
4468    2634
4429    1703
2634    1703
1703    1703
1742    1703
4468    1703
....        ....
```

Comment: For a start you you're limiting it to only 5 results, so remove your `LIMIT 0, 5` to start with. An SQL fiddle would be nice too so we actually know what we're working with

Comment: I don't think there is a way in MySQL without repeating the query.

Comment: reword your question: rather than trying to describe a solution, describe the problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please tell me how?

Comment: `select * from (... your original query ...) as t1 cross join (... your original query ...) as t2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t_outer.tid as tid, t_inner.tid as tid_group, t_inner.count, t_inner.name
FROM taxonomy_index as t_outer
JOIN (
  SELECT t.tid ,count(*) AS count, td.name, td.vid
  FROM taxonomy_index t 
  JOIN taxonomy_term_data td ON td.tid = t.tid
  WHERE t.created > 0 AND td.vid = 1
  GROUP BY t.tid
) t_inner
WHERE t_outer.created > 0 AND t_inner.vid = 1
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

yields:

```
TID     TID_GROUP   COUNT   NAME
4429    4429        3       A1
4468    4429        3       A1
4429    4429        3       A1
2634    4429        3       A1
4429    4429        3       A1
2634    4429        3       A1
4429    2634        2       B1
4468    2634        2       B1
4429    2634        2       B1
2634    2634        2       B1
4429    2634        2       B1
2634    2634        2       B1
2634    4468        1       C1
4429    4468        1       C1
4468    4468        1       C1
4429    4468        1       C1
2634    4468        1       C1
4429    4468        1       C1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88f5e2/29

credit where credit is due: [count without group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259611/count-without-group)

updated: sorry, forgot to constrain the outer data.
update 2:  and i also forgot about the tid listing column

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari how about now, is that what you're after? it must be late, i keep forgetting things... if it is not, please provide more data in the sqlfiddle b/c the relationships are not clear :(