# SQL query that returns a subset of table plus column containing count for whole table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table named PEOPLE (Sex, Age, Weight) listed here:

```
Sex Age Weight
M   10  81   
F   21  146
M   32  179
F   40  129
F   58  133
```

I would like to have the following data returned (Sex, Age, Weight, Count(*) as SexCount from PEOPLE where Age < 35):

```
Sex Age Weight  SexCount
M   10  81      2
F   21  146     3
M   32  179     2
```

I have found answers that work if I want to return all the people in the table ([count without group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259611/count-without-group)).

But I have not found an answer if I want SexCount to include the total count from the whole table...and not just the total count from my returned subset. In other words, I want my returned data to just include people who are less than 35 years old, but I want the SexCount to include the count for all people in the table regardless of age.

Anyone know a query that will return the data I want from the table example above? I am using Oracle if it makes a difference.

I tried using this SQL phrase in my query:

```
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Sex) as SexCount
```

But it only counted the number that were in my query results, and not in the whole table as I require (and explained above). Thanks.

Comment: Most likely impossible, but you should provide the queries you already have to let people take a look.

Comment: SQL Server has a function called partition by which will allow to aggregate any way you please...Not sure of the oracle equivalent. It would help if you post some sample data and expected results

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a single column on your output that is built using different criteria than the rest of the group.  No matter your SQL system, you will need to invoke a second record-set.

Thankfully, since you're not really looking for an aggregate query, this can be done with a single subquery on your FROM list.

```
SELECT P.Sex, P.Age, P.Weight, T.SexCount
FROM PEOPLE as P
INNER JOIN (SELECT Sex, COUNT(*) As SexCount FROM PEOPLE GROUP BY Sex) AS T
  ON P.Sex = T.Sex
WHERE P.Age < 35;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will give it a try and reply back with my findings.

Comment: My query was a bit more complex than my example of course, but Oracle kept giving me an 'invalid identifier' error with your suggested answer. I ended up putting a Select statement in my Select statement like this "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Lei_Job_Time LJT where...) as Count, Column2, Column3 FROM...WHERE..." and it worked! Your answer may be just fine but I could not get it to work.

Comment: You may want to try setting up an example on SQLFiddle or a similar site in the future; just be sure to switch to a compatible rdms for what you're targeting.