# How can i show information of two tables? With INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, inner-join

I'm deveoping a windows application with C# and MYSQL.
But i have a doubt, i need to show differents things from differents tables (inner join i'm supose)..
I have one table called tbl_horas, and in this table i'm saving different hours, ex:

```
IdHora | Hora | Meta.
1      | 7:30 | 40
2      | 8:30 | 20
3      | 9:30 | 40
4      | 10:30| 40
```

And i have another table called Products, and in this table i'm saving information like this:

```
IdProduct | Hour | Description | ActualDate
1         | 7:30 | Product one | 2017-04-19
2         | 8:30 | Product two | 2017-04-19
3         | 9:30 | Prod  three | 2017-04-19
```

And the thing is, how can i show information like this?

```
Hora (From tbl_horas) | Meta (from tbl_horas) | Description (from tbl_products) | Cantidad (from tbl_productos)<- This gonna ve a count for all products that have the hour 7:30, or another..
7:30              | 40            | Product one                     | 20
8:30              | 20            | Product two         | 15
```

I have this sql sentence, but i can't do that this works for the thing that i want..

```
SELECT 
  tbl_horas.Hora, 
  tbl_horas.Meta, 
  tbl_horas.Turno, 
  Count(tbl_productos.Serial) 
FROM tbl_horas 
INNER JOIN tbl_reportes 
  on tbl_horas.IdHora = tbl_reportes.IdHora 
INNER JOIN tbl_productos 
  ON tbl_reportes.IdProducto = tbl_productos.IdProducto;
```

I'm gonna show this in a gridview, and if some hours doesn't have products, this gonna show 0 in the Cantidad..
I'm sorry for the english haha, can someone help me?

Comment: I suppose it is too late or impractical to put `IdHora` in table `Products` instead of `Hour`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Count(), you need to use "Group By".

Try adding: GROUP BY tbl.Hora to the end of your statement.

Note, however, that by grouping the results, you will lose the meaning of some of the columns.
To fix this, you could try running a sub-query for the count column ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259611/count-without-group)).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `count()` using `group by` and then perform a `join` like

```
select th.hora, th.meta,
xx.description, xx.counthora
from tbl_horas th join (
select hora, description,
count(*) as counthora from products
group by hora) xx on th.hora = xx.hora;
```