# MySQL Showing Count with 2 Tables Without Grouping

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have 2 tables and I am attempting to show the count for each item_id to show how many related items they have from their group_id number.

table_1
| item_id |  item_name   |
|---------|--------------|
|       1 | Red Scarf    |
|       2 | Blue Scarf   |
|       3 | Yellow Socks |
|       4 | Blue Socks   |
|       5 | Brown Socks  |

table_2
| item_id | group_id |
|---------|----------|
|       1 |        1 |
|       2 |        1 |
|       3 |        2 |
|       4 |        2 |
|       5 |        2 |

desired_table_output
| item_id | group_id | number_in_group      |
|---------|----------|----------------------|
|       1 |        1 |                    2 |
|       2 |        1 |                    2 |
|       3 |        2 |                    3 |
|       4 |        2 |                    3 |
|       5 |        2 |                    3 |

The closest related question I found was from here: [count without group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259611/count-without-group) but none of the examples seem get the desired output.

--
**Failed Method #1**

```
SELECT
  t.name,
  t.phone,
  COUNT('x') OVER (PARTITION BY t.name) AS namecounter
FROM
  Guys t
```

This won't work as my version is 5.7

--
**Failed Method #2**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6f1cd/148

```
SELECT
t1.item_id,
t1.item_name,
t2.counter
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS number_in_group
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY group_id
) t2
ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

This displays only the first row that has a count - but I need each row to have it.

--
**Failed Method #3**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6f1cd/150

```
SELECT
t1.item_id,
t1.item_name,
t2.counter
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS number_in_group
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY item_id
) t2
ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

This shows each item_id, but shows the count as 1 for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you

```
SELECT
t1.item_id,
t1.item_name,
g.counter
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
JOIN (
  SELECT group_id, COUNT(*) AS counter
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY group_id
) g ON t2.group_id = g.group_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6f1cd/172

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join using the second query like this

```
SELECT
t1.item_id,
t1.item_name,
t2.counter
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS counter
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY group_id
) t2
ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

Comment: This was my initial thinking, but this just gives a count on the 1st row with the group_id.
The other rows show up as "null".
So if I later attempt to search WHERE item_id = 2, it displays the count as null.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6f1cd/170

Comment: Yes for id 2 there is no value then it will be null ??

Comment: What is your expected result

Comment: Are u mean group by   GROUP BY item_id

Comment: number_in_group what is the logic behind this